# Finite measure space & sigma-finite measure space

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

A measure space $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ is finite if $\mu(X)<\infty$.

It is equivalent to saying that $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ is finite if $\mu(E)<\infty$ for all $E \in \Sigma$

A measure space $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ is $\sigma$-finite if X is a countable union of sets with finite measure.

1. Does $\sigma$-finiteness imply that $\mu(E)<\infty$ for all $E \in \Sigma$?
2. If $\mu(E)<\infty$ for all $E \in \Sigma$, dose it imply $\sigma$-finiteness or finiteness of a measure space?

Comment: Do you know any examples of $\sigma$-finite measure spaces?

Comment: I know that Real numbers with Lebesgue measure is sigma finite, but not finite just by taking all unit intervals [k, k+1] etc

Comment: Not finite because $\mu(\mathbb{R})=\infty$.  So that's your answer to 1.

Comment: I think both of your questions would be resolved at once if you recalled that $X$ itself is an element of $\Sigma$.

Comment: oh yea, I see it. Thanks pizza!

Answer (score 6):

Probably the best example of a finite measure space is $[0, 1]$ with its usual structure, and the best example of a $\sigma$-finite measure space is $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual structure. So, are all the measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ finite in measure? That should answer your first.

For your second, consider what $\mu(X) < \infty$ implies.

edit to add: and I think pizza has said it much better than me.

Comment: Thanks user24142!